# Arduino String's replace function and customized replace function with char array

Tags: c, arrays, string, arduino, stm32

I'm planning to alternate some string operations, especially 'replace'. I saw some articles about String type's efficiency in Arduino(for example, https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/). Of course just using String is not troublesome but I thought about the time-efficiency of String object. So I tried to process replacement of the string with only character arrays.

First of all, I made a 'replace' function using only some of 'character arrays'. And then, I tried to compare with traditional String operations by executing very many same oprations. I do not think the two code is exactly same because of some of calloc(), but to use the function I thought calloc() is essential for my function.

I used Nucleo-K432LC evaluation board and Arduino 1.8.9.

```
#define strpos(A, B) (int) (strstr(A, B) - A)

char* replace_char(char* dst, char* needle, char* replacer) {
    int offset;
    int k;
    int ns, rep;
    char* temp;
    if (strlen(dst) + strlen(needle) < strlen(replacer) + strlen(dst)) {
        ns = strlen(replacer) - strlen(needle) + strlen(dst) + 1; rep = 1;
    }
    else {
        ns = strlen(dst) + strlen(needle) + 1; rep = 0;
    }
    temp = (char*)calloc(ns, sizeof(char));
    strcpy(temp, dst);
    if ((offset = strpos(dst, needle)) < 0) return NULL;
    for (k = 0; (k < strlen(replacer)) && replacer[k] != '\0'; ++k)
        temp[k + offset] = replacer[k];
    for (k += offset; k < strlen(replacer) - strlen(needle) + strlen(rep ? dst : temp); ++k)
        temp[k] = dst[k - strlen(replacer) + strlen(needle)];
    temp[k] = '\0';
    if (strpos(temp, needle) < 0) {
        dst = temp;
        return temp;
    }
    else
        return replace_char(temp, needle, replacer);
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    unsigned long t0 = millis();

    for (int k = 0; k < 10000; ++k) {
        char* str = (char*) calloc(16, sizeof(char));
        char* str2 = "NANA";
        char* str3 = "1234KAHCS1234";
        strcat(str, "KKNANAHAHACA");
        char* newstr = replace_char(str, str2, str3);
        if (k >= 9999)
            Serial.println(newstr);
        free(str);
        free(newstr);
    }
    Serial.println(millis() - t0);

    unsigned long t1 = millis();
    for (int k = 0; k < 10000; ++k) {
        String str = "";
        String str2 = "NANA";
        String str3 = "1234KAHCS1234";
        str.concat("KKNANAHAHACA");
        str.replace(str2, str3);
        if (k >= 9999)
            Serial.println(str);
    }
    Serial.println(millis() - t1);

    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, !digitalRead(LED_BUILTIN));
    delay(1000);
}
```

My STM32 said that character array using one delayed 600ms, and using string caused 468ms delay. The final results are same for two operations.
I tried to shorten the lengths of arguments, and the function seemed to work successfully. However the speed was slower at character-array-based operations. Also it seemed that there was no error for string-based operations. I ran the sketch for one day, but I failed to found any case of 'efficiency'. Did I mis-focused? Using character-array-based would be better than string-based operations? Or, is the reduction of speed caused by solely due to lack of my programming experience?

Comment: You have 15 `strlen` calls within 20 lines of function, try to optimize that first.

Comment: For one, you're calling `strlen` multiple times unnecessarily.

Comment: Any algorithm that takes longer than **1** ms is a complete fiasco. This code isn't salvagable. Ditch the PC programming, ditch heap allocation, ditch Arduino, study embedded systems.

Comment: @kiranBiradar I think you pointed out exactly. I tried to remove some of strlens to pre-assigned integers. Speed-up realized. 10000 times running of the function delayed 225ms(character-array) and 468ms(string). I wonder if some optimization could be tried for other parts.

Comment: The language you're programming with here is not C but C++! My pet peeve with Arduino programming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is just horrible written. It is so bad - that even it does not make any sense to analyze it. BTW forget the recursion in the uC development.  Always think about the algorithm. Here you have much simpler and definitely more efficient:

```
char *findAndReplace(char *haystack, const char *needle, const char *repl)
{
    size_t needle_len;
    size_t repl_len;
    size_t haystack_len;
    const char *pos = strstr(haystack, needle);

    if(pos)
    {
        needle_len = strlen(needle);
        repl_len = strlen(repl);
        haystack_len = strlen(haystack);

        if(needle_len != repl_len)
        {
            memmove((void *)(pos + repl_len), (void *)(pos + needle_len), haystack_len - (pos - haystack) + 1);
        }

        memcpy((void *)pos, (void *)repl, repl_len);
    }
    return haystack;
}
```

of course the haystack has to be:

1. modifiable
2. big enough to accommodate the amended string

> but to use the function I thought calloc() is essential for my function.

Forget about malloc and friends when programming uCs.  Otherwise you will get into serious problems. Dynamic memory allocation in the low memory enronments is a bit tricky , and "big computer" mechanisms fail miserably here